# Problema con caracteres ñ y acentos generando un JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo problemas con los acentos y caracteres especiales, generando un **json** con **php** en los acentos, por ejemplo:

```
T\u00c3\u00a9cnologia = Técnologia
```

ya lo intenté arreglar con `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");` pero nada.

```
    <?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-                        version,x-requested-with');
    //header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");


    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $bd = "u703093142_wifi";


    //Creamos la conexión
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
    or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base     de datos");

   //generamos la consulta
   $sql = "select upload.*,promociones.nombre_input
                 from upload
                     inner join promociones on      upload.idGaleria=promociones.imagen_gallery limit 4";
   mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8



   if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

   //$clientes = array(); //creamos un array

   /*
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   { 

  $titulo=$row['titulo'];
  utf8_decode($nombre_input=$row['nombre_input']);




  $data[] = array('nombre_input'=> $nombre_input,'titulo'=> $titulo);

  }

  */

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $data[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
 } 

 $close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
 or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base  de datos");



  //Creamos el JSON
  $json_string = json_encode($data);
  //echo $json_string;




  echo '{"datos":'.$json_string."}";

  //Si queremos crear un archivo json, sería de esta forma:
  /*
 $file = 'clientes.json';
 file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
  */


 ?>
```

Comment: Tu base de datos que cotejamiento tiene, tus campos que cotejamiento tiene...?

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Todo esta utf8_general_ci

Comment: Haber coloca tu código de PHP para ver que estas haciendo.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco revisa el codigo

Comment: No entiendo el problema que tienes, json es normal que codifique los caracteres especiales, el receptor lo tiene que descoficar y ya está. haz la prueba con json_decode

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Me tira Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/datos.php on line 56
{"datos":} si aca le meto while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $data[]=array_map('utf8_decode', $row);  //utf8_decode la palabra Técnologia aparece  T?cnologia
}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, si es que no quieres que los caracteres especiales se convierten en formato `\u....`

El receptor tiene que revertir la codificación, normalmente lo hace automáticamente, por ejemplo en `php` usando `json_decode(data_json)` lo convierte sin más.

Pero aun así quieres que no se conviertan,  usa la opción `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

**Test**

```
$response = "Técnologia";

echo json_encode($response); //T\u00e9cnologia
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //Técnologia
```

Documentación oficial de [PHP json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 5):

Hola estimado prueba agregando esta línea en tu archivo de conexión:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
```

Solo debes agregar eso y ya se mostrará correctamente, ya no necesitas poner en el head de cada archivo, solo en el archivo de conexión.

Answer (score 3):

Yo también me he encontrado con el mismo problema y la solución ha sido combinando dos de las respuestas que te dieron. Haciendo esto:

```
   //preparamos la conexión a la base de datos
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "miDataBase");
    // esto es necesario a la hora de recuperar datos en utf 8
    mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");
```

$app->get("/tabla", function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($db) {

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla;";
  $query = $db->query($sql);
  $respuesta = array();

  while($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      $respuesta[] = $fila;
  }

    return json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

});

Espero que os sirva de ayuda

Comment: Esta respuesta combinada fue mi solución!

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes arreglar con esta funcion:

```
function utf8_converter($array){
      array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item){
          $item = utf8_encode( $item ); 
      });
      return json_encode( $array );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hola es muy simple solo con esto.

utf8_encode() que tiene como finalidad codificar cadenas a formato UTF-8. Es muy útil cuando trabajas con api rest o xml

```
"titulo"=> utf8_encode($consulta[nombre])
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola Andres, bienvenido a Stack Overflow y gracias por tu aporte. Mira [como escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), agrega una descripción explicando tu código, explica como esto resuelve la duda del OP. Una ves mas te doy la bienvenida y te animo a que sigas aportando a la comunidad :)

Comment: podrías explicar brevemente que hace utf8_encode en tu respuesta?

Comment: Hola  utf8_encode() que tiene como finalidad codificar cadenas a formato UTF-8.   Es muy útil cuando trabajas con api rest o xml

Answer (score 1):

Es mi primera aportacion :) aqui les dejo mi solución.

```
<?php 
    //Importing Database Script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); // AQUI AGREGUE UTF-8

    $sql = "Select * from acompanante";

    //getting result      $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($r);  //obtenemos el numero de resultados de busqueda      

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result,array(
            "id"=>$row['id'],
            "nombre"=>$row['nombre'],
            "apellido"=>$row['apellido'],
            "telefono"=>$row['telefono'],
            "dni"=>$row['dni'],
            "idred"=>$row['idred'],
            "usuario"=>$row['usuario'],
            "clave"=>$row['clave'],
            "estado"=>$row['estado']            
            ));


    }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));  // AQUI AGREGUE JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

    mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

ESPERO LES SIRVA

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. mira [tour] y [answer] para saber como funcionamos y como responder una pregunta. Tu código no tiene nada que ver con el código posteado en la pregunta. Podrías aclarar como debería arreglarse ese código comparado con el tuyo?

Answer (score 1):

en mi caso que estoy usando composer con slim, se ha solucionado al poner

```
mysqli_set_charset($bd,"utf8");
```

antes de realizar una petición.

ejemplo de una petición por get seria esta:

```
// Listar productos
$app->get('/productos', function() use($app,$bd){
    mysqli_set_charset($bd,"utf8"); //poniendolo antes de la petición
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM productos;';
    $query = $bd->query($sql);

    $productos = array();
    while ($producto = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $productos[]=$producto;
    }
    $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' =>200,
            'data' =>$productos
        );
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //tambien ha servido esta opción

});
```

Comment: erprom, bienvenid@ a SOes. Ya que el OP no especifico si esta o no esta usando composer o slim, te invito a [edit] tu respuesta para que responda la pregunta bajo los terminos expuestos. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

A mí me sirvió solo colocar:

```
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8"); en mi conexion.
```

Si leo el texto JSON retornado sin convertirlo a objeto de JavaScript, sí muestra los caracteres `JES\u00daS` de lo contrario, no lo hace.

Comment: Hola @jesus. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. No obstante, esto es exactamente el mismo código que está en la pregunta. esperaría ver un poco más de justificación en una respuesta. ¿Cuándo exactamente sucede el error? ¿Por qué? ¿Cómo solucionaría tu respuesta el problema de la pregunta? La idea es generar contenido con la mayor calidad posible. Más info en [answer]