# Los acentos salen mal codificados usando JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Hay alguna manera de reparar éste codigo? La base de datos si tiene los acentos y los muestra bien, está codificada en utf8mb4_general_ci

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-full" id="ver_mensaje" name="ver_mensaje" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MensajeUModal"><?php echo $btnOpciones[2]; ?></button>
    
  <div class="modal fade" id="MensajeUModal" style="background: url("/images/azul.jpg") center center fixed;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="animated fadeIn dzjRvv"></div>
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="btnCloseHover" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: #0a0a0a;" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="tUniverso animated zoomIn"></div>
    <div class="tUniversoM animated flipInX">
      <div class="mensajeU"></div>
    </div>
  </div>       
  </div>
</div>
<?php require("complementos/scripts2.php"); ?>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en scripts2.php. En item.mu_mensaje que le da la informacion a un objeto HTML, los mensajes no salen con los acentos (Saliendo con caracteres raros) y no logró averiguar porque, trate de meter metas y contents y no funcionaron

```javascript
$('#MensajeUModal').on('show.bs.modal.bs.modal', function (e) { //Corre la funcion mensaje universo
              mensaje_universo();
    });
    function mensaje_universo(){ //Mostrar el mensaje del universo
            aleatorio();
            $(".tUniversoM").fadeOut();
            $(".tUniverso").fadeIn();
            $(".mensajeU").text("");
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"function/puntosDAO.function2.php", //Se comunica con esta url para cargar el mensaje y dar puntos
                    dataType:"JSON",
                    data:"&tipo=cargar_mensaje", //Este viene de la clase puntosDAO.class en function/class
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.state == "ok"){
                            console.log("success");
                            $(".tUniverso").fadeOut();
                            $(".tUniversoM").fadeIn();
                            $.each(data.result, function(i, item){
                                $(".mensajeU").text(item.mu_mensaje);           
                            });
                            $.ajax({
                                                type:"POST",
                                                url:"function/puntosDAO.function2.php", //Se comunica con esta url para cargar el mensaje y dar puntos
                                                dataType:"JSON",
                                                data:"&tipo=obtener_usuario&registro_id="+registro_id,
                                                success: function(data){
                                                    if(data.state == "ok"){                                             
                                                        $.each(data.result, function(i, item){
                                                            var puntosActuales = parseInt(item.registro_puntos)
                                                            registro_puntos = 500 + puntosActuales;
                                                            $("#EnergyPointBS").text(registro_puntos);
                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                type:"POST",
                                                                url:"function/puntosDAO.function2.php",
                                                                dataType:"JSON",
                                                                data:"&tipo=updatepuntos&registro_id="+registro_id+"&registro_puntos="+registro_puntos
                                                            });                                                         
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });     
                        }else{
                            console.log("failed");
                            $(".tUniverso").fadeOut();
                            $(".tUniversoM").fadeIn();
                            $(".mensajeU").text("El universo aún no esta listo para ti...");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 4000);
        }   
    
        var objetos = new Array(); //Randomiza entre las imagenes de aqui
        objetos[0] = "imagen0";
        objetos[1] = "imagen1";
        objetos[2] = "imagen2";
        objetos[3] = "imagen3";
    
    function aleatorio() { //Selecciona una de las 4 imagenes al azar 
            var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * objetos.length);
            $(".dzjRvv").addClass(objetos[azar]);
    }
```

Esto es lo que tengo en PuntosDao.function2.php

```
case "cargar_mensaje": 
    $p = new puntosDAO2();     
    $resultados = $p->cargar_mensaje(); //Corre la funcion del mensaje de la clase
    if(sizeof($resultados)>0){
        $r["state"] = "ok";
        $r["result"] = $resultados;
    }else{
        $r["state"] = "error";
        $r["result"] = "No pasa nada";                  
    }  
break;
```

Este es el query que se encuentra en la clase de PuntosDAOClass2. Se trae una frase al azar y usa encode

```
class puntosDAO2{
    private $r;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->r = array(); 
    }
    
    public function cargar_mensaje(){ //Trae el mensaje de la base de datos al azar
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM reto_mensajes_universo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($con, $q);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $file);
        }
        return $this->r; //Lo manda
    }
```

Los mensajes salen así si tienen acentos. En donde puede estar el error que aparece aquí?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez esto pueda responder a tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15953/problema-con-caracteres-%C3%B1-y-acentos-generando-un-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, hay varios motivos por los que se puede originar este problema, el más común es la codificación de caracteres HTML, puedes añadir

```html
<!-- Desde HTML5 -->
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<!-- Antes de HTML5 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Si el problema persiste, algo está causando el mismo en el backend puedes usar `htmlentities` para arreglar esto

```php
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["codificar"])) { # !empty() para prevenir warning
        print htmlentities($_POST["codificar"]);
    }
?>
```

Tras esto, todos los caracteres especiales se convertirán en códigos únicos de codificado que HTML mostrará.

```js
const result = JSON.parse('{"abc":"&#xF1;&#xE9;..."}');
abc.innerHTML = result.abc;
```

```css
p {
  padding:23px;
  font-family:Arial,
}
```

```html
<p id="abc"></p>
```

O puedes usar `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` con el `json_encode` desde el backend.

```
print(json_encode("Este texto contiene acentos (á)", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)) // Este texto contiene acentos (á);
```

Si vas a guardar un texto con caracteres especiales en tu base de datos, usa `htmlentities`, esto codificará todos los caracteres especiales, ejemplo: una comilla (") la convertirá a su equivalente, en &quot;

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema, al igual que tu, busque en varios foros y probe varias soluciones. La que me funciono y con la cual me quede fue esta que se agrega en el codigo php y es una funcion:

```
function utf8_converter($array){
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item){
    $item = utf8_encode( $item ); 
});
return json_encode( $array );
}
```

con esa funcion, lo que hace es que todos los caracteres de letras con tilde y hasta la misma "ñ" te la transforma, y despues puedes comprobar que el archivo json se envia de forma correcta. Eso ocurre por problemas en la codificacion del JSON por los caracteres extraños.